# CFn lintをVSCodeでインストールしたらエラーが出ました

Tags: vscode

VSCodeにて、CFn lintをインストールし、有効にしました。
早速CFnを記述したところ、冒頭に以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
    [cfn-lint] /bin/sh: cfn-lint: command not found
Go to https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/#install for more help

    [cfn-lint] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
Go to https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/#install for more help
```

このエラーはGUIだけでなく、`pip install cfn-lint`コマンドを実行しないといけない
ということでしょうか？
また、このコマンドはVSCodeのターミナルで、カレントディレクトリをどこにしたら良いのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教示願います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

インストールした "CFn lint" が VSCode 拡張機能の CFn lint (CloudFormation Linter) を指しているなら、これは単に `cfn-lint` を呼び出すための機能に過ぎないので、参照しているマニュアルにある通り、`cfn-lint` をインストールする必要があります。

`pip install cfn-lint` については VSCode と直接関係なく、(Python / pip が使えることが前提で) コマンドプロンプトなどから実行すれば OK なはずです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
早速pip install cfn-lintを打ってみたところ、 pip: command not foundと表示されたので、pipでパッケージをインストールしないといけない、ということになりますか？
またその際のコマンドは　pip install numpy　となりますか？

Comment: pip コマンドが認識されていないようですが、そもそもお使いの PC に Python の実行環境はインストールされていますか？

Comment: Python の実行環境はインストールしていないです…
てっきりそのままできるものかと思っていました。